# How do I remove every file that has x in its title?

Tags: shell, zsh, find

I have a lot of directory where there are hundreds of files.

In every directory there are pairs of my_file-01.jpg and my_file-€01.jpg

I want to remove every file that contains € sign in its title: how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

`find` does the job:

`find . -iname "*€*" -delete` gets rid of all files whose name matches "*€*", be careful, find goes into subdirectories as well, if you don't want that you have to tune the find params a little

Comment: I'll upvote yours if you'll upvote mine ;-)

Comment: mine is better cause it's case insensitive :P

Comment: Ok, right then, wiseguy, put up your dukes. Show me a capital '€' then.

Comment: Just for information : you can use `-maxdepth 1` with `find` to use only the current directory

Comment: @Elenaher: But if it is only about the current directory, you could simply use `rm *€*`

Comment: @wzzrd: gooood point! :D

Comment: @wzzrd: Well it might be defined, there is a capital ß as well ;)

Comment: @Marcel: The OP did kind of imply it was in a flat directory - your answer may well be the best one.

Comment: @Marcel : of course, my point was just to say that one could use the maxdepth flag to control deepness. Moreoever, find will allow you to do more elaborate things (like deleting only old files etc...)

Answer (score 5):

Something along the lines of

```
find -name '*€*' -delete
```

You might want to try this first, to see if the correct files would be delete:

```
find -name '*€*' -ls
```

Comment: That should be `'*€*'`, right?

Comment: @Marcel: yes, it should. I also used double quotes (but it doesn't really matter in this situation)

Comment: @Marcel: True and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In each example, the first command lists files whose name contain a `€` and the second command deletes them.

Using GNU find (as found on Linux):

```
find -name '*€*' -ls
find -name '*€*' -delete
```

Add `-type f` after `-name '*€*'` if you only want to match regular files and not directories as well.

Using find, relying only on POSIX features:

```
find . -name '*€*' -print
find . -name '*€*' -exec rm {} +
```

Add `-type f` after `-name '*€*'` if you only want to match regular files and not directories as well.

Using bash 4 or zsh:

```
echo **/*€*
rm **/*€*
```

Under zsh only, `**/*€*(.)` restricts the matching to regular files, excluding directories.

---

If you only want to list files that have `€` in their names and such that an identical file without the `€` exists, here are standard find and zsh solutions.

```
find . -name '*€*' -type f -exec sh -c 'cmp -s -- "$0" "$(printf "%s" "$0" | tr -d "€")"' {} \; -print
find . -name '*€*' -type f -exec bash -c 'cmp -s -- "$0" "${0//€/}")"' {} \; -print
echo **/*€*(.e\''cmp -s -- $REPLY ${REPLY//€/}'\')
```